# Discord Bot Slash Command not appear on Win10

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I use slash command in my Windows 10 computer, it doesn't appear.
But in Android, it appears!
[image: Slash Command in win10]

[image]

Comment: Slash commands can take 1-2 hours to sync globally. If you have not specified the guilds for which the commands must be visible in, wait for some time.

Comment: In addition, you can try to refresh your discord client by pressing ctrl + R

Comment: yeah i tried to refresh it, but it didn't work for me. @moinierer3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recent Discord bug that's effecting all apis, including discord.py. In other words, there's nothing that can be done about it for now. Here's the message that the discord.py developers have left about it:

> There are currently a couple of bug that prevent App (slash) commands from
> being registered or only a part of them do or the command registers
> but does not work. Or the guild_only/default_permissions
> kwargs/decorator was ignored. Started: 6 days ago Mobile clients are
> unaffected by this
>
> There is an open forum by discord about this in the developers server
> (discord.gg/discord-developers) here:
> https://canary.discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/969042921024266240
>
> And issues on the docs repo:
>
> 1. https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/4859
> 2. https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/4856
>
> Confirmed by Danny here:
> https://canary.discord.com/channels/336642139381301249/669155775700271126/970063555544088596
> (yes, this is important)
>
> Things to check:
>
> 1. Check the integration tab for your guild to see if the command is there if, continue else the command didn't sync.
> 2. Try restarting discord, altering the permissions in the integration tab and re-syncing (button and code)

Answer (score 0):

disable Legacy Chat Input under Accessibility
Source: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/4959

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).